# Insert text into large existing file

Tags: c#, file

I have a file that contains about 2000 lines of text that I need to add a few lines to. My initial solution was to just copy the existing file to a new file and then add a few lines at the end of it. That was until I realized that the last line in the file had to always be the last line. So now I need to add my new lines before that one line of text. I know that I can just read the entire file, save it to my program and then write everything to a new file with my extra lines included. But since the file has that many lines I wanted to know if it was a better way to do it.

Comment: From a performance perspective it would be much better if you could append the new lines to the end of the file instead of prepending them. You would need to reverse things in your application, of course, if that is a requirement.

Comment: @Robert I know, this is why that was my initial solution. But the line that is currently the last line has to always be the last line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to copy it into a new file. There's no way to inject data into the middle of a file, unfortunately.

However, you don't have to load it into memory to do that. You can use a `StreamReader` and read only one line at a time, or better yet, the `System.IO.File.ReadLines` method.

```
int newLineIndex = 100;
string newLineText = "Here's the new line";
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(outputFileName))
{
    int lineNumber = 0;
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(inputFileName))
    {
        if (lineNumber == newLineIndex)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(newLineText);
        }
        else if (lineNumber > 0)
        {
            writer.WriteLine();
        }

        writer.Write(line);

        lineNumber++;
    }
}
```

Of course, this becomes substantially easier if you're comfortable assuming that the new line will always go at index zero. If that's the case, I'd be tempted to forgo much of this, and just go with a simple `Stream.CopyTo` after writing the first line. But this should still work.

```
string newLineText = "Here's the new line";
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(outputFileName))
using (var reader = File.OpenRead(inputFileName))
{
    writer.WriteLine(newLineText);

    reader.CopyTo(writer.BaseStream);
}
```

Of course, there are any number of ways to perform this, with different trade-offs. This is just one option.

Comment: It actually doesn't matter where the new lines go, as long as they are not the last lines in the file. And with that in mind, you suggest that I create a new file, write my new lines to the start of that and then copies the old file?

Comment: @JesperEvertsson Yeah, that's probably what I would do. I added a bit of an example of how I'd probably think about adding them to the beginning.

Comment: I tried impelemting your second solution, but for me that adds the new line at the end of the file

Comment: @JesperEvertsson Interesting. I'm not sure why that would be happening on the second one. The first one would have had that problem, I realize now, and I've edited to fix that a bit. But the second one should be fine for that.

Comment: I used a modified version of the first solution you provided and now it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

> that I can just read the entire file, save it to my program and then write everything to a new file with my extra lines included.

Not everything needs to be written. Just write the inserted lines and lines after the inserted lines to the original file, starting from the position (byte index) of the inserted lines.

Comment: The problem with this is that I don't know how big the file will be in advance and it varies from file to file

Comment: @JesperEvertsson Read it into your problem, find the position of the insertion, and then write the new lines and the affected lines.